# Sencha Touch carousel Image issue

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, carousel

I have create a vbox layout view and added carousel images in that as follows:

```
var imgSlider1 =  Ext.create('Ext.carousel.Carousel',{
direction: 'horizontal',
singleton: true,
height:300,
width:250,
id: 'imgSlider',
bufferSize: 2,
defaults: {
    styleHtmlContent: true
},
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'image',
        cls: 'my-carousel-item-img',
        src: 'resources/images/training.jpg'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'image',
        cls: 'my-carousel-item-img',
        src: 'resources/images/upcoming_programms.jpg'
    }
]
});




Ext.define('RasovaiApp.view.HomePage',{
extend: 'Ext.Container',
fullscreen: true,
requires:[
imgSlider1
],
config:{
    scrollable: true,

    layout: {
        type: 'vbox'
    },


    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                height: 300,
                type: 'hbox'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    height:300,
                    width:50,
                    html: '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'+
                        '<head>'+
                        '</head>'+
                        '<body>'+
                        '<img src="resources/images/arrow_left.png" alt="Previous"     width="30" height="60" align="left"   onclick="'+'Ext.getCmp(\'imgSlider\').previous();console.log(\'previous\')'+'"/>'+
                        '</body>'+
                        '</html>'
                },
                Ext.getCmp('imgSlider'),
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    height:300,
                    width:50,
                    html: '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'+
                        '<head>'+
                        '</head>'+
                        '<body>'+
                        '<img src="resources/images/arrow_right.png" alt="Next" width="30" height="60" align="right" onclick="'+'Ext.getCmp(\'imgSlider\').next();console.log(\'next\')'+'"/>'+
                        '</body>'+
                        '</html>'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'+
                '<head>'+
                '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />'+
                '<title>Home</title>'+
                '<h1 align="center">Home</h1>'+
                '</head>'+
                '</html>'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'+
                '<head>'+
                '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />'+
                '<title>Untitled Document</title>'+
                '</head>'+
                '<body>'+
                '<p align="center">Raso Vai Ayurved is</a> an unique effort to bring ancient Ayurvedic science to the services of modern man. Our main work is providing Trainings, conducting Courses, Workshops, Consultation, offering Treatments and Panchakarma.</p>'+
                '<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="http://rasovai.com/index.html">'+
                '<label></label>'+
                '<br />'+
                '</body>'+
                '</html>'

        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            html: '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'+
                '<head>'+
                '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />'+
                '<title>Untitled Document</title>'+
                '</head>'+
                '<body>'+
                '<p align="center"><strong>Raso Vai,</strong><br />'+
                'Morjim-Aswem Road <br />'+
                'Mardi Wada, Morjim, North Goa, <br />'+
                'India<br />'+
                'Center- +91-9623 556828 <br />'+
                'Mobile- +91-9850 973458 <br />'+
                'Email: <a href="mailto:info@rasovai.com">' +
                'info@rasovai.com</a></p>'+
                '<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="http://rasovai.com/index.html">'+
                '<label></label>'+
                '<br />'+
                '</body>'+
                '</html>'


        }
    ]
}
});
```

I have added above view to the viewport in app.js as:
    Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('RasovaiApp.view.HomePage'));
The thing is when I run the above code it runs perfectly fine with on the desktop browser, but when i build the application and run it on desktop browser, it only shows one carousel image with two radio button. And when i package the same application for android mobile device and runs on it, then it doesnot show an any of the image, but it shows two radio buttons which indicates it is loading two items in the carousel.

I think the problem is with the var imgSlider1 or carousel instance. Can any one help me?
Any help would be greatful.

Thanks
Ishan jain

Comment: Instead of `Ext.getCmp('imgSlider')` in HomePage can't you define `imgSlider` component in Homepage itself? Why do you want a global variable ** imgSlider1**?

Comment: I used imgSlider1 as a global variable so that i can call the next and previous method with onClick of prev / next button.                                  How can I define carousel component to a variable inside the javascript. It won't allow me to build the application as "var: imgSlider = 'something'" syntax is not allowed in Sencha touch 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, first thing first, you must not use `onClick` attribute on HTML element, instead you should bind events to element when required. So check my code to see how to bind `tap` event to an image.

Secondly I was asking to put carousel code inside view like this:

```
Ext.define('RasovaiApp.view.HomePage',{
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    fullscreen: true,
    config:{
        scrollable: true,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                layout: {
                    height: 300,
                    type: 'hbox'
                },
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        height:300,
                        width:50,
                        items: [{
                            xtype:'image',
                            src: 'resources/images/arrow_left.png',
                            height:300,
                            width:50,
                            listeners: {
                                tap : function(me, evt){
                                    console.log("Tap on left");
                                    Ext.getCmp("imgSlider").previous();
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype : 'carousel',
                        direction: 'horizontal',
                        singleton: true,
                        height:300,
                        width:250,
                        id: 'imgSlider',
                        bufferSize: 2,
                        defaults: {
                            styleHtmlContent: true
                        },
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'image',
                                cls: 'my-carousel-item-img',
                                src: 'resources/images/training.jpg'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: 'image',
                                cls: 'my-carousel-item-img',
                                src: 'resources/images/upcoming_programms.jpg'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        height:300,
                        width:50,
                        items: [{
                            xtype:'image',
                            src: 'resources/images/arrow_right.png',
                            height:300,
                            width:50,
                            listeners: {
                                tap : function(me, evt){
                                    console.log("Tap on right");
                                    Ext.getCmp("imgSlider").next();
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                html: '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'+
                    '<head>'+
                    '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />'+
                    '<title>Home</title>'+
                    '<h1 align="center">Home</h1>'+
                    '</head>'+
                    '</html>'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                html: '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'+
                    '<head>'+
                    '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />'+
                    '<title>Untitled Document</title>'+
                    '</head>'+
                    '<body>'+
                    '<p align="center">Raso Vai Ayurved is</a> an unique effort to bring ancient Ayurvedic science to the services of modern man. Our main work is providing Trainings, conducting Courses, Workshops, Consultation, offering Treatments and Panchakarma.</p>'+
                    '<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="http://rasovai.com/index.html">'+
                    '<label></label>'+
                    '<br />'+
                    '</body>'+
                    '</html>'

            },
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                html: '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'+
                    '<head>'+
                    '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />'+
                    '<title>Untitled Document</title>'+
                    '</head>'+
                    '<body>'+
                    '<p align="center"><strong>Raso Vai,</strong><br />'+
                    'Morjim-Aswem Road <br />'+
                    'Mardi Wada, Morjim, North Goa, <br />'+
                    'India<br />'+
                    'Center- +91-9623 556828 <br />'+
                    'Mobile- +91-9850 973458 <br />'+
                    'Email: <a href="mailto:info@rasovai.com">' +
                    'info@rasovai.com</a></p>'+
                    '<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="http://rasovai.com/index.html">'+
                    '<label></label>'+
                    '<br />'+
                    '</body>'+
                    '</html>'


            }
        ]
    }
});
```

You can use id attribute of carousel to fetch and invoke method on it. I can see you are putting whole forms in panel as HTML, that is also not right approach, Sencha has [Form](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel) component you should use it.

Comment: I am new to sencha, javascript, php. I have posted a new question, any help would be greatful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657005/email-form-detail-in-sencha-touch.  Thanks Ishan jain