# Sencha Touch Ajax Request Error: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Tags: ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest, sencha-touch, cors

I am making an Ajax request to remote server and sending parameters as POST method.
But I am getting following response:

```
**"MLHttpRequest cannot load http://rasovai.com/mobilecontact1.php?_dc=1369189135731. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.  "**
```

I read about this error and found out that it is because of CORS, so I add header to the request as follows:

```
 Ext.Ajax.defaultHeaders = {
                                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                                        'Accept': 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',
                                        'Accept': 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:   true',
                                          'Accept': 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST',
                                        'Accept': 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Depth, User-Agent, X-File-Size, X-Requested-With, If-Modified-Since, X-File-Name, Cache-Control'
                                    };
```

but still I am getting the same error in response.

I am able to hit the url on server, but not able to pass the parameters.

Can anyone help me in this regard?

Thanks
Ishan jain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Chrome browser you can use `--disable-web-security` flag to allow cross domain requests and if you are building this into app this will work fine. Have a look at this thread for more details : [How to use json proxy to access remote services during development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118053/how-to-use-json-proxy-to-access-remote-services-during-development)

Comment: One issue I see here is, disabling the web security will work only during development but when you test this functionality on device, it will again throw the same CORS issues.

Comment: I am using AJAX(not JSONP) proxy in my iPad app and it is working fine without any errors. Looks like desktop browsers and mobile webview have different security policies.

Comment: Please have a look on this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767351/loading-dynamic-data-from-xml-file-in-grid-issu

Comment: please have a look on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978741/sencha-image-gallery-view

Answer (score 2):

Those headers need to be sent by the server, not the client.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any other workaround, which i can make on the client side, so that I dont need to make changes on the server. And actually I am not experience with the server, so can you tell me how I can make changes on the server side to make it working.

Comment: There isn't much you can do on the client side to get around CORS. To enable those headers server side, take a look at: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Do you think json proxy can help for cross domain requests?

Comment: Absolutely. If you have the ability to host a proxy on the same domain your script is running on that would get around the CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the params to the server then you can do it as following.

```
 Ext.Ajax.request({
            url : serverURL,
            jsonData : requestParams,  //  Object which encapsulates the request params
            method : 'POST',
            withCredentials: true,
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,

           // List of header params can be sent as follows
            headers : {
                "Content-Type" : "application/json",
                "Accept" : "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"http://localhost:8080",
                "Authorization":auth
            },

            username : 'mobiliser',
            password : 'secret',
            success : function(response) {
             }
            failure : function ()
             {
             }
```

As you said in your question that, the server is on a different domain, you may have to use  JSONP request.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks-
Gendaful

Comment: Again, the `Access-Control` headers need to be sent by the server, not the client. They do absolutely nothing when sent from the client.

Comment: If your sencha application is not able to communicate to the remote server directly due to Cross Origin Issues then create a servlet on the client side and place it on the same server as your sencha app. Your sencha app will communicate to the servlet and servlet will talk to the remote server. This is one work around to come out from the CORS issue.

Comment: Thank you gys for your help.Yes I think idbehold is also correct. Hey Gendaful can I put php script file on a local server and send parameters to php file and then PHP script will send email. Can you guide me in that way? Please have a look on this question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657005/email-form-detail-in-sencha-touch-giving-exception"

Comment: Hi Gendaful, actually my php script is not working, so can you help me  for sending the mail using servlet?

Comment: Hi Ishant, I would be happy to help but I dont have access to the servlet code now. But let me tell you, that would be a simple servlet which talks to your remote server and send the request and get the response and pass the response data to your sencha application.Your sencha application will make a call to this servlet using Ext.Ajax since sencha app and servlet resides in the same domain. Hope it helps.

Comment: useDefaultXhrHeader: false option helped me out. Thanks @Gendaful