# Sencha image gallery view

Tags: javascript, html, sencha-touch, image-gallery

I am creating a grid(gallery) view to show the images. Application fetch the images from the server and display it in grids. I can create this view using XTemplate and it is giving me appropriate result. My Xtmeplate code is:

```
tpl:  Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
        '<div class="gallery" id="photos">',
        '<tpl for=".">',
        '<img src="{media:this.getURL}{picname}" width="30" height="30"      class="thumbnail" data-fullimage="{media:this.getURL()}{picname}" alt="{description}"/>',
        '</tpl>',
        '</div>',{
            getURL: function(){

               return Gallery.utils.globalVar.getRemoteDirPath();
            }
        })
```

The problem is that the images are of big size and I want to display them in small thumbnail. So when I run the application on the mobile device, the application becomes very slow and it hanged up. The reason may be because it simultaneously downloading all the images and rendering on the view.

Can anyone suggest the possible solution that how I can fast the process or any different way to do it.

Thanks
Ishan jain

Comment: have separate thumbnail images of small dimension and size on server and fetch these thumbnails in grid. And after user selection show actual image on different view. This will improve performance of both downloading and rendering images.

Comment: Actually I already have thought of that. But the client requirement is that he don't want put any duplicate copies and wants to show thumbnail and full view with the same image.

Comment: I am not sure how would client know if you are using same image or different size of same image in your app? Anyways if you want you can use sencha IO service for image resizing http://www.sencha.com/learn/how-to-use-src-sencha-io/ . In any case loading large image and resizing it on client is BAD idea.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ThinkFloyd the client need not necessarily know or have a say in the mode of implementation especially if it would not have detrimental impact on the outcome. Thinkfloyd presents a very valid and implementation friendly approach, on the other hand, the client is giving you more work than is necessary by insisting that you take this alternate approach. S/he might be willing to compromise if you communicate things to him/her effectively. You only need to have a thumbnails folder within the images folder for the thumbnails images to link to.. I hope you managed resolve it in the end!